# Using NodeJS,Express and JQuery GET request arrives on server as a POST

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I am new to Node.JS and Express so forgive me if this is a newbie question. I am using a JQuery EasyUI DataGrid which is configured to use "get" as the method to populate.
However when the request arrives on the Express server it SEEMS to be a POST that comes in and the wrong server method is being called.

Stuck on this for a couple of days now... please help...

EXTRACT FROM app.js

```
 app.configure(function(){
   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
   app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
   app.set('view engine', 'jade');
   app.use(express.favicon());
   app.use(express.logger('dev'));
   app.use(express.bodyParser());
   app.use(express.methodOverride());
   app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
   app.use(express.session());
   app.use(app.router);
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 });

 app.configure('development', function(){
   app.use(express.errorHandler());
 });

 app.get('/', routes.index);
 app.get('/users', user.list);
 app.get('/TrainingPlans', TrainingPlans.findAll);    // THIS IS THE ONE I WANT TO USE 
 app.get('/LoadSampleData',populateDB);
 app.get('/ClearAllTrainingPlans',clearTPsFromDB);
 app.get('/TrainingPlans/:id', TrainingPlans.findById);
 app.put('/TrainingPlans/:id', TrainingPlans.updateTrainingPlan);
 app.delete('/TrainingPlans/:id', TrainingPlans.deleteTrainingPlan);
```

EXTRACT FROM INDEX.HTML

```
 <table id="tpstable" title="Training Plans" class="easyui-datagrid"      style="width:550px;height:250px"
        url="/TrainingPlans"
        toolbar="#toolbar"
        method="get"
        rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
     <thead>
     <tr>
         <th field="name" width="50">Name</th>

         <th field="_id" width="70">_id</th>

         <th field="description" width="100">Description</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
 </table>
 <div id="toolbar">
     <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true"      onclick="create_trainingplan()">Create Plan</a>
     <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true"      onclick="edit_trainingplan()">Edit Plan</a>
     <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-remove" plain="true"      onclick="delete_trainingplan()">Remove Plan</a>
 </div>
```

GOT IT WORKING INT THE END by setting the Data
DataGrid from JS using instead of in the HTML table definition.

```
$('#tpstable').datagrid({
    url:'/TrainingPlans',
    toolbar:"#toolbar",
    method:"get",
    rownumbers:"true",
    fitColumns:"true",
    singleSelect:"true" 
 });
```

Thank you all for your help...  and

Cormac

Comment: Show us a bit of code, at least the relevant parts of the DataGrid configuration, your Express setup (middleware and such) and your routes.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that, while it is easy to rule out a failure of the V8 engine, you'll get more information by providing more code. They're co-variant!

Comment: Where is your client-side javascript invoking the request?

Comment: @BryanMoyles I'm guessing DataGrid handles that itself.

Comment: The table definition in Index.html has the url and method parameters set as the /TrainingPlans  and get

Comment: BTW earlier post of code had the URL incorrect as I had been playing with a variation of the url syntax. What's  in the post now is what is not working for me...

Comment: @user2298589 how do you see that a `POST` is being generated instead of a `GET`? Also, does the POST request use the correct URL (`/TrainingPlans`)?

Comment: In know it's a post because 1) the console output (presumably by Express is : "POST /TrainingPlans 404 1ms   and 2) because if I change the routes to comment out :app.get('/TrainingPlans', TrainingPlans.findAll); and use  app.post('/TrainingPlans', TrainingPlans.findAll) instead it works.   Cormac

Comment: I want to use POST to Add a TrainingPlan  ie   
app.get('/TrainingPlans', TrainingPlans.findAll);
app.post('/TrainingPlans', TrainingPlans.addTrainingPlan);

Comment: @cormackeogh have you looked at alternative ways of configuring DataGrid? Either with `data-options` or using JS.

Comment: _“However when the request arrives on the Express server it SEEMS to be a POST”_ – if you want advise on things that “seem” to be something, talk to a soothsayer. If you want to discuss your problem with other _developers_, then __verify__ stuff instead of assuming something.

Comment: No will try anything though..  can you recommend anything in data-options ?

Comment: @CBroe  I have verified as much as I can based on my own expertise... please see above the two reasons why I believe it is a POST that comes to the server

Comment: Woo Hoo   it works... I set up the DataGrid from JS using   


$('#tpstable').datagrid({
        url:'/TrainingPlans',
        toolbar:"#toolbar",
        method:"get",
        rownumbers:"true",
        fitColumns:"true",
        singleSelect:"true"
    });

Thank you all for your help...  and comments

Cormac